# Translating JavaScript multidimensional array to Java

Tags: javascript, java, multidimensional-array

I'm working on simple genetics program involving theoretical flowers. For color assignment I'm using a simplified [Punnett Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punnett_square) created thusly,

```
var momDom = mommaFlower.ColorOne;
var momRec = mommaFlower.ColorTwo;

var dadDom = papaFlower.ColorOne;
var dadRec = papaFlower.ColorTwo;

var punnet = [
  [0,0],
  [0,0],
];
punnet[0][0] = [momDom, dadDom];
punnet[0][1] = [momDom, dadRec];
punnet[1][0] = [momRec, dadDom];
punnet[1][1] = [momRec, dadRec];

return punnet[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
```

so there is a relatively equal chance of any of the four color combinations for the child.

My trouble lies in translating this to Java, namely the destructuring assignment. What I have so far is

```
//getDomColor() = {255, 187, 187, 1.0}
float[][][][] punnet = {
  {
    {m.getDomColor(), f.getDomColor()},
    {m.getDomColor(), f.getRecColor()}
  },{
    {m.getRecColor(), f.getDomColor()},
    {m.getRecColor(), f.getRecColor()}
  }
};
```

where the return on getDomColor, and getRecColor is a float array of rgb values. I had hoped it would be just as simple as JS's way, but I've since found out that Java does not have destructuring assignment. My question is, what would be the best way to translate my JS Punnett Square into Java, considering what I have so far.

Comment: `float[][][][] punnet` is a four dimensional array, if you want to create a 3d array it's just `float[][][]`.

Comment: I tried that, but because getDomColor() returns an array, it throws an error unless it's four dimensional.

Comment: I think once you need an array with that many dimensions its time to consider turning some of those arrays into their own objects so its easier to deal with or leaving the arrays in their objects until you need to read their values.